# Can't import android-switch-backport

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, backport

I'm trying to use the [android-switch-backport](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) to make my Android app compatible with earlier versions. I import it using gradle as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "http://JRAF.org/static/maven/2"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':OurProject')
    compile (''org.jraf:android-switch-backport:1.1')
    instrumentTestCompile(files('libs/espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar'))
}
```

I then try to import the Switch class in my fragment using the following line:

```
import org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch;
```

The strange thing is that it knows the whole part of this url up until the actual class. So it recognizes `org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.`, but it only doesn't know the `Switch` class.

When I try to use it in my xml file like so:

```
<org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I get an error saying it can't find R anymore (i.e.: R doesn't build anymore because the use of the Switch in my xml creates an error). I'm using the `Android Studio IDE`.

Any ideas how I could solve this? Any help would be very very welcome!